# XA Datasource 1PC optimization

Tags: java, transactions, ejb, jta, xa

I am working with JBoss EAP 6.4 (Java EE 6) and I have a question related to the way the application server is dealing with XA Datasources (through EJB / JTA) and if the 2 phase commit (2PC) is always used or if an "optimization" is applied.

Let's say I have this:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public class MyEjb {
   @EJB
   private MyFirstEjb first;

   @EJB
   private MySecondEjb second;

   // Transactional processing
   public void process() {
      first.processJpaStuff();
      second.processJpaStuff();
   }
}
```

Let's say that :

- MyFirstEjb do JPA queries using XA Datasource 1.
- MySecondEjb do JPA queries using XA Datasource 2.

I am using XA datasource because these EJBs can be used in other cases where 2PC is required (along with another datasource or a JMS provider).

I now would like to distinguish several cases:

1. MyFirstEjb and MySecondEjb are deployed in the same application (EAR)
2. MyFirstEjb and MySecondEjb are deployed in separate applications (EARs) within the same application server
3. MyFirstEjb and MySecondEjb are deployed within different applications servers

and sub-cases:

a) XA Datasource 1 = XA Datasource 2

b) XA Datasource 1 != XA Datasource 2 (same database)

c) XA Datasource 1 != XA Datasource 2 (different database)

I guess b) and c) are managed the same way. There is a global transaction and each datasource collaborate with the XA transaction manager. A 2PC is applied.

What about cases 1.a) and 2.a) ? Since both are eventually using the same datasource, I guess there is some kind of optimization that does not require a global 2PC transaction to be processed?
If yes, is there any official (JTA / JBoss / ...) link that explains this?
Is it the same thing with all application servers / implementations?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

The JTA (transaction coordinator) knows nothing about EJBs or applications. It's concerned only with XAResources and the associated transaction branches.  The normal case is that the JCA managing the connection pool used by the JPA for the entity beans, will provide the JTA with one XAResource per datasource used. The JTA assigns each a different branch qualifier under the same global tx id.

During transaction termination the JTA prepares each XAResource and it's at this point that the optimization kicks in. If the db engine detects that it has multiple branches (connections/XAResources) for the same global tx, it may return PREPARED from the first XAResource, but READ_ONLY from the remaining resource(s). Assuming the tx has as a result only one PREPARED resource and the rest are all read-only, it can then optimize the remaining part of the termination accordingly. see e.g.

http://narayana.io/docs/product/#two-phase-variants

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/java.920/a96654/xadistra.htm#1061004

Note that depending on the vendor, 'db engine' and 'database' are not exactly the same thing. Some systems will host multiple dbs on the same server and allow the optimization to work across them, whereas others may treat each as a separate transaction engine scope and not optimize such cases. Datasources may also differ only in userid/schema used for the connection, relying on the permissions/schema namespacing to isolate applications without requiring a distinct database for the purpose. The optimization almost always works in such cases.

In some cases where the apps use the same XADatasource, the JCA registers just one XAResource with the JTA, potentially allowing it to use the more aggressive 1PC optimization instead.

Whilst it's true that connections may switch between local and XA transaction context, it's currently not possible for the JTA to take advantage of this. Since resources are enlisted only on demand, the system doesn't know how many are going to participate in the transaction until it reaches the termination stage. The JTA spec group has previously discussed allowing configuration, similar to the way tx timeouts are set, which would allow the application to indicate at begin that a tx is expected to be single resource, or more generally to list what XAResources it's expected to contain. That information would allow the JTA to drive the resource in local tx mode rather than XA mode where appropriate, eliding the start/end/prepare protocol calls. It would also remove the need to manually optimize such cases by deploying both XA and non-XA datasources for the same database in an application. It's not currently on the roadmap though.

Comment: Wow... thank you for this detailed explanation and for these important links! It is very interesting and makes it much more clear even if this is a complex subject.
And it confirms that optimizations are vendor specific.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

**1.MyFirstEjb and MySecondEjb are deployed in the same application (EAR)**

When datasources are different, as you probably know, if the driver and the underlying datasources are not able to Join a global transaction, or if the driver is not configured to join global transaction, you will get a specific error.

For the other cases, besides that the ideal scenario is a business layer dealing with both datasources and all the clients deal with the business layer (different app dealing with same datasource should be avoided at all). This is what may happens.

**2.MyFirstEjb and MySecondEjb are deployed in separate applications (EARs) within the same application server**

If deployed on the same application server, but with different .ear the client access them trough a remote interface, therefore each one start a completely different thread/transaction (REQUIRES_NEW). The client will get an EJBException if something goes wrong. There is no global transaction from client perspective.

**3.MyFirstEjb and MySecondEjb are deployed within different applications servers**

The same apply if the ejb are deployed on different app server. They are accessed trough a remote interface, therefore they start a brand new transaction each.

Comment: Thank you for these additional clarifications.
Indeed,  if the driver is not configured to join global transaction you will get an XAException.
But you don't answer to my main concern about optimization. I have found an interesting post ([link](http://integrationspot.blogspot.fr/2011/03/jta-transactions-local-and-global.html)) that stands "XA data source can support two-phase commit coordination, **as well as local transactions**" + "[...]the application server performs an **"only resource optimization"** and interacts with the resource manager in a RMLT.".
Is it the way it works?

Comment: There is also this answer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130934/jta-datasources-without-transactions#answer-5452025](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130934/jta-datasources-without-transactions#answer-5452025) which is interesting : "it is totally possible to start a non-XA transaction over an XA-supporting resource, and commit it locally". But is it what happen when accessing the same datasource and relying on JTA and EJB CMT?